# How to consult the repeated numbers and add them up, in mongodb?

Tags: mongodb

I made this query below to be able to filter the time of an array:

```
db.twitter_search.aggregate([
{ "$addFields": {
        "tweet_created_at": {
            "$toDate": "$tweet_created_at"
        }
    } }, { "$project": {
      "hours":{"$hour":"$tweet_created_at"}}
 }])
```

The output of this array is this:

```
[{'_id': {'$oid': '5e1779510e5b76daeb9e9eb3'}, 'hours': 20}, {'_id': {'$oid': '5e1779510e5b76daeb9e9eb4'}, 'hours': 20}, {'_id': {'$oid': '5e1779510e5b76daeb9e9eb5'}, 'hours': 20}, {'_id': {'$oid': '5e1779510e5b76daeb9e9eb6'}, 'hours': 19}, {'_id': {'$oid': '5e1779510e5b76daeb9e9eb7'}, 'hours': 19}, {'_id': {'$oid': '5e1779510e5b76daeb9e9eb8'}, 'hours': 19}, {'_id': {'$oid': '5e1779510e5b76daeb9e9eb9'}, 'hours': 19}, {'_id': {'$oid': '5e1779510e5b76daeb9e9eba'}, 'hours': 19}, {'_id': {'$oid': '5e1779510e5b76daeb9e9ebb'}, 'hours': 18}}]
```

I need the query to return me the duplicate numbers and how many. How do I do that?

If anyone can help me, thank you very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to `$group` `hours` and count repeated values with `$sum` operator. Last `$match` stage serves to filter non-repeated numbers

```
db.twitter_search.aggregate([
  {
    "$addFields": {
      "tweet_created_at": {
        "$toDate": "$tweet_created_at"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$project": {
      "hours": {
        "$hour": "$tweet_created_at"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$hours",
      count: {
        $sum: 1
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $match: {
      _id: {
        $gt: 1
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[MongoPlayground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/fA8YQrGzJaf)

Comment: Dude, it worked! Thank you! One more question: is there any way to make this search orderly? Maybe ``` db.twitter_search.aggregate([
  {
    "$addFields": {
      "tweet_created_at": {
        "$toDate": "$tweet_created_at"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$project": {
      "hours": {
        "$hour": "$tweet_created_at"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$hours",
      count: {
        $sum: 1
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $match: {
      _id: {
        $gt: 1
      }
    }
  },
  {
     $sort : { _id : -1, count: 1  }
      }
]) ```

Comment: Sure. It's a valid solution.